# Swift - Use of unresolved identifier (Objective-C class)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

So I was going to start moving my app over to swift (since it just seems so much easier to work with), and I figured Id be able to do a little at a time since you're supposed to be able to use it with existing objective-c code.

The problem Im having is it seems the interoperability doesn't seem to be working for some reason.

- I have a MODULE_NAME-Bridging-Header.h file and the import statements:
  [image: Bridging Header File]
- I have it specified under Build Settings > Swift Compiler > Objective-C Bridging Header
  [image: Build Settings]

That's all that needs to be done to make it work right? Thats all Ive been able to find online at least.

Here is the error Im getting:
[image: Error]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

You need to provide the whole file path from the root folder, not just the file name.

under Build Settings > Swift Compiler > Objective-C Bridging Header put:

**MobileScripts/MobileScripts-Bridging-Header.h**